# Cannot boot into windows after installing Fedora

Tags: fedora, windows, dual-boot, grub

I had a PC with a Windows and Ubuntu dual boot. Same disk with 2 paritions of 500GB each.
I decided to install Fedora instead of Ubuntu. So I downloaded project Nobara and installed it. During the installation, I remember that I `reclaimed` the ubuntu partition and `/boot/efi` partition. Now when I reboot I don't see windows as an option in Grub.

How can I boot into Windows if I want to.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `reclaim` in this case could have meant "reformat", which means that other installed boot loader disappear.

- Put back `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi' into the EFI-partition (copy from some other windows-install of the same version)
  Copy other "Microsoft"y-looking folders/folders you find too
- Edit EFI config with `efibootmgr`:

  `efibootmgr -c  -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/sdb -p 2`
  (Adapt `sdb2` to wherever your EFI partition is)
- update/reinstall `grub` to (re)detect the foreign OSs

I had to look up "Nobara", it seems like a newish fedora-offshoot. Perhaps also consider using one of the more mainstream distros which are less likely to break boot behavior of existing systems without severe warnings.

Comment: Your answer is detailed and I definitely learnt a thing or two. Earlier I wiped everything and reinstalled windows and then fedora. So I can't confirm if your answer works and mark it as correct, but it does seem correct.